# Statistical Test to Compare Count Data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, count-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I need to compare two vectors containing count data with different sample sizes.

The example problem is the following:

I have conducted an experiment on two groups of people that eat some number of apples until Experiment Day 50.

```
Group_1 = c(10, 11, 17, 20, ..., 12); N=40
Group_2 = c(11, 21, 17, 20, ..., 24); N=63
```

How can I compare these two groups?
Is there better approach than just comparing the means or medians for two groups (T test, Mann-Whitney test)?

Comment: Well, what do *you* want to compare?

Comment: What sort of conclusion is more useful to you: one group eats more apples, or the distribution of the number of apples eaten is different? (or indeed something else again)

Comment: What is the population that you wish to estimate the parameters for? For example: Are the groups of people in your experiment a sample from groups that are a larger population of people?

Answer (score 0):

I think one option would be to fit a generalized linear model with famility distribution Poisson or, to allow extra variation above the Poisson, negative binomial. From the model fit you can check what is the difference between Group1 vs Group2. For example, in R using negative binomial GLM:

```
library(MASS)

set.seed(1)
Group_1 = rnbinom(n= 40, mu= 20, size= 30)
Group_2 = rnbinom(n= 63, mu= 25, size= 30)

dat <- data.frame(group= rep(c('g1', 'g2'), c(length(Group_1), length(Group_2))), 
    count= c(Group_1, Group_2))

fit <- glm.nb(data= dat, count ~ group)
summary(fit)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = count ~ group, data = dat, init.theta = 37.80452487, 
    link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.63992  -0.86535   0.01778   0.78150   2.38985  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  3.03855    0.04311  70.476   <2e-16 ***
groupg2      0.13486    0.05425   2.486   0.0129 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(37.8045) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 109.63  on 102  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 103.43  on 101  degrees of freedom
AIC: 665.37

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  37.8 
          Std. Err.:  14.1 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -659.372
```

Comment: Poisson would not be could for inference like a likelihood ratio test or t-test. The Poisson distribution assumes that the variance is equal to the mean, and that seems a bit unlikely as it is not a Poisson process and can have all kinds of different variances.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus *Poisson would not be could for inference like a likelihood ratio test or t-test*, sorry I don't understand this, perhaps you got the sentence a bit mixed up...? I agree that Poisson is probably inappropriate. In the text I mention this and in my example I use a negative binomial.

Comment: For the use of a negative binomial the criticism is the same. We can not learn anything about the difference between the sampled people within the groups by looking at the daily variance. Some people eat more than others, there is variation there, and the daily variation does not give good information about that.