# How can I assess the statistical significance of one year's total cases of a disease against previous years?

Tags: statistical-significance, disease

Rookie question - is it possible to compare a single year's total number of cases of a disease in a specific region compared with previous years. I have a data set showing total yearly cases of a certain disease over the past 10 years. I want to know whether the increase in 2022 is statistically significant compared to previous years. Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many different ways in which you can do that. Some ways are simple but don't take into account all your information. Some other ways are more complex and take more information into account.

First, you should know that the technical name for your data is "count data". Using that term will greatly help you find relevant information. The book [Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis](https://mregresion.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/agresti-introduction-to-categorical-data.pdf) has a lot of pointers.

One way to go about your problem would be to fit a Generalized Linear Model (GLM) to your data. The intuition behind this, as applied to your problem would be the following:

Every year there is a certain probability of someone in the population getting infected, or lets call it **infectious force**. Besides the **infectious force**, there is some normal random variability that can change the number of infections from year to year. For example, in two years with the same *infectious force*, you may see 930 infections the first year and 943 the second. But random variability can only have so much effect, e.g. it may explain a difference between 930 and 943, but not between 930 and 10000 cases.

You observed a certain number of infections in the year 2022. You want to know whether the difference with respect to previous years can be explained by random variability, or whether it is evidence of a higher *infectious force*.

The *infectious force* is an invisible variable that you don't know. Statistically speaking, it could be the probability of success of a Binomial distribution, or the expected mean of a Negative Binomial or a Poisson distribution.

The GLM approach would be to fit a GLM regression model to your count data, to estimate what the *infectious force* was for the first 10 years, and whether it changed in the year 2022. For this first you need to choose a model of what the variability in your data looks like. You could use Poisson regression, Binomial (logistic) regression by using the total number of people in the population, or negative binomial regression. Then, you would fit a model to your count data, which has a shared *infectious force* between the previous 10 years (that is a parameter A), and which has the same *infectious force* + a difference (the difference being parameter B) for the year 2022. Then you can ask the model whether parameter B is statistically different from 0, that is, if that parameter B is needed to explain the data of year 2022, or whether that datapoint can just be explained by the standard variability.

Some resources for doing this kind of thing (though you will have to adapt them for your problem) are found here

https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/poisson-regression/

[Statistical Test to Compare Count Data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/489093/statistical-test-to-compare-count-data)

https://www.guru99.com/r-generalized-linear-model.html

There are even more sophisticated analyses that you could do. For example, it could be expected that there is some variability in the *infectious force* in the previous 10 years. Does the year 2022 also depart from the normal between-year variability for this disease? That you could answer with a Generalized Linear Mixed Model, or with a Hierarchical Bayesian Regression.

Anyhow, implementing any of this will require careful thinking about the model that your fitting, and how to adapt other coding examples to your specific problem.